# Jenkins: Log Parser Plugin configuration

Tags: jenkins, logparser

i'm quite new in Jenkins. I would like to use the log parser plugin to parse the console output of jenkins. 
Like the documentation explains I have to add a file, which is containing my parsing rules.
So there is my question:
How do i upload files to jenkins? Do they need to be located in the projects workspace? My workspace is connected with a git repository. So i have to commit that file?

For example the file /tmp/rules.txt how do i get the rules.txt in the /tmp/ folder (and which folder is it, the workspace/tmp or the /tmp/ of the server itself)?

Do I have to transfer it via ssh?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file dont have to be in the projects workspace. You don't have to uploat it on Git. Just create file somewhere on the computer, where jenkins runs.
You must change Global Configuration (/jenkins/configure). There is a section "Console Output Parsing". In description you can put, for example, : "Rules1" and in "Parsing Rules File" - path. Then in each job you want to use this rules configure Post-build Actions -> Console output (build log) parsing.

Comment: Sorry but this random location of the parsing rules sound a bit stupid to me, jenkins jobs can run on many machines and this plugin doesn't give any indication regarding a single place where you are supposed to put the rules.